# How to covert the date string range into datatime data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to convert the following **raw string (date range)** into ruby datetime datetype.

How to finish it on Rails  ?

#### raw string

```
"2014 April/July  24-1"
```

#### convert to ruby datetime variable

```
start_date = 2014-04-24 
end_date = 2014-07-01
```

#### raw string

```
"2015 April  06-20"
```

#### convert to ruby datetime variable

```
start_date = 2015-04-06
end_date = 2015-04-20
```

Comment: If your raw string is always formated in the same way, then use `Date.parse` method with custom format string.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
# In order to generate
# year = 2014
# months = "April/July"
# days = "24-1"

/(?<year>\d{4})\s*(?<months>\w+\/\w+)\s*(?<days>\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2})/ =~ "2014 April/July  24-1"

date1 = "#{year} #{months.split('/')[0]} #{days.split('-')[0]}"
date2 = "#{year} #{months.split('/')[1]} #{days.split('-')[1]}"

start_date = Date.strptime(date1, "%Y %b %d") #=> Thu, 24 Apr 2014
end_date = Date.strptime(date2, "%Y %b %d")   #=> Tue, 01 Jul 2014
```